# How do you create a three way contingency table in R when you only have probabilities?

Tags: r, machine-learning, statistics, probability, glm

I'd like to create a three level contingency table in R. Let's assume that one of my variables is a categorical variable with two levels, one of my levels is a categorical variable with two levels and the third variable is a categorical variable with three levels.

I know that you have to use the

```
table()
```

function, but I'm not sure how to set things up. Most of the explanations that I've seen online assume that you are given the data in a format similar to [this](https://corpuslinguisticmethods.wordpress.com/2014/02/07/how-to-make-a-contingency-table-in-r/), but I just an actual contingency table that is similar to the one in [example 1 here](https://onlinecourses.science.psu.edu/stat504/book/export/html/102).

How do I make a contingency table when I don't have an actual data file?

For example, in the example that I linked to could I create factors like this?

```
yesFactor<- c(19,0,11,6)
```

For example this is my code below

```
#do this to use the mass library
datos2.array <- array(c(16,7,15,34,5,3,1,1,3,8,1,3),
                  dim=c(2,2,3),
                  dimnames=list(Conduct=c("Buena","Mala"),
                                Riesgo=c("N","R"),
                                Adversidad=c("Bajo","Medio","Alto")))
my.table <- ftable(datos2.array)
model2 <- loglm(~ Riesgo + Adversidad, data = datos2.array)
```

When I try printing the table I get the following

```
               Adversidad Bajo Medio Alto
Conduct Riesgo                           
Buena   N                   16     5    3
        R                   15     1    1
Mala    N                    7     3    8
        R                   34     1    3
```

I need a 2X3X2 table with N and R being factors of Bajo, Medio and Alto.

I've also tried the other way

```
datos2.array <- array(c(16,7,15,34,5,3,1,1,3,8,1,3),
                   dim=c(2,3,2),
                   dimnames=list(Conduct=c("Buena","Mala"),
                                 Adversidad=c("Bajo","Medio","Alto"),
                                 Riesgo=c("N","R")))
```

and that is wrong as well.

Comment: Please don't link to examples, just put one into your post. If you have to make up your own example, that's even better.

Comment: I don't think you can obtain a table without data... It's like trying to get the conditional distributions of random variables when you only know the marginal ones.

Comment: @FelipeGerard could I do something like make a glm?

Comment: Depends on the particular model. In some cases yes. Minimal example?